# How to setup Amazon Lambda with micro services in Node.js

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices

I am looking forward to work in a Amazon Lambda with Node.js
They call it server less, So is it a better way to host our code then traditional hosting servers ?

I am open for the suggestions, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called serverless as you dont manage and maintain the underlying server and the runtime.
Basically you write your code in one of the supported languages, say node.js, and then configure events that will trigger your code.
Example in case of AWS, the events can be a API GW call, a SQS message, a SNS notification etc.

So it can be better depending on what you are planning on doing.
Do note that there are certain limits that AWS imposes by default on accounts for AWS Lambda.
Also there can be slight startup penalty for a Lambda.
A plus point of Lambda vs Hosting your code in EC2 is that with Lambda you dont get charged if your code is not used/triggered.
However, do note that for functions that have heavy usage it might be better to 
host your own EC2.

Most important a Lambda has to be stateless.

Considering all the above factors you can take a call on whether AWS Lambda and Serverless Architecture fits your needs.

Comment: So Lambda is not preferable to handle heavy traffic or heavy computing ? if yes can we use lambda as a backend processor that deals with database and EC2 for our frontend use ?

Comment: Lambda can talk to a RDS, there are certain deployment items that you need to take care of if you want that. Heavy computing yes, but again depends on your use case. I havent worked with a lot of frontend use cases that use Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the details